# Slug returns Reverse for '' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, slug, slugify

I am trying to make it so when I view a blog from any particular link on my website, the url displays [www.example.com/view-blog/slug](http://www.example.com/view-blog/slug). I have got it working for my images and image title. But I cannot get it to work with blog titles.

It keeps returning the error:

***Reverse for 'viewblog' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['view\-blog/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\Z'].***

**Models.py**

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    blog_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    slug = models.SlugField()
    blog_article = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True, default="ici")
    blog_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images", default="default.png")
    blog_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    blog_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    blog_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slug or slugify(self.blog_title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_title
```

**Views.py** ***EDIT: ADDED ALL VIEWS.***

```
    def blogPage(request):
    posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(blog_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-blog_date')[:4]
    context = {'posts': posts}
    
    return render(request, 'blog.html', context)

def blogsPage(request):
    posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(blog_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-blog_date')
    context = {'posts': posts}

    return render(request, 'blogs.html', context)

def searchBlogs(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST.get('searched', False);
        searched_blogs = BlogPost.objects.filter(blog_title__icontains=searched)
        
        return render(request, 'search-blogs.html', {'searched': searched, 'searched_blogs': searched_blogs})

def viewBlog(request, slug):
    try:
        blog = BlogPost.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except BlogPost.DoesNotExist:
        print("ViewBlog with this slug does not exist")
        blog = None
    return render(request, 'view-blog.html', {'blog': blog, 'slug': slug})
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.galleryPage, name='gallery'),
    path('gallery/', views.galleryPage, name='gallery'),
    path('contact/', views.contactPage, name='contact'),
    path('blog/', views.blogPage, name='blog'),
    path('blogs/', views.blogsPage, name='blogs'),
    path('search-blogs/', views.searchBlogs, name='searchblogs'),
    path('view-image/<slug:slug>/', views.viewImage, name='viewimage'),
    path('view-blog/<slug:slug>/', views.viewBlog, name='viewblog'),
    path('thank-you/', views.thankyouPage, name='thankyou'),
    path('about-me/', views.aboutmePage, name='aboutme'),
]
```

****One of my templates I wish to link to viewblog page from ** **( I have tried to replace .id on my urls with .slug but this is what gives me the error.****

```
<body>
<header>{% include 'navbardesktop.html' %}</header>
  <div class="blog-container">
    <h1 class="all-blog-title" id="all-blog-title" style="text-align: center;">All Blogs</h1>
    <br>
      <div class="search">
        <form class="d-flex" method="POST" action="{% url 'searchblogs' %}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search keyword" name="searched">
          <button id="search-btn" class="btn btn-secondary">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <br> 
    <hr id="blog-hr" style="width:50%; margin-left:25% !important; margin-right:25% !important;" />
    <div class="blog-post-container">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Blog List
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: #d6d6d6 ;">
          {% for post in posts %} {% if post.blog_published is True %}
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'viewblog' post.id %}">{{post.blog_title}}</a></li>
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        {% for post in posts %} {% if post.blog_published is True %}
          <div class="col-md-4" id="blog-col">
              <div class="blog-post">
                <div class="blog-content">
                      <img class="blog-img"src="{{post.blog_image.url}}"alt="My image"/>
                      <h2 class="blog-title">{{post.blog_title}}</h2>
                      <hr id="blog-hr" style="width: 90%" />
                      <article class="blog-article">
                        <p>{{post.blog_article|truncatechars_html:265|safe}}</p>
                      </article>
                      <a href="{% url 'viewblog' post.slug %}"class="btn btn-secondary"type="button"class="blog-button">Read More...</a>
                      <p class="blog-date">Posted on: {{post.blog_date}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              {% endif %} {% empty %}
              <h3>No Blog Uploads</h3>
              {% endfor %}
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: please check if post.slug is empty because the error message tells that you are giving an empty parameter to {%  url 'viewblog' empty_para %}

Comment: Sorry about this, I'm relatively new. But in what way do you mean empty @Razenstein

Comment: post.slug (the parameter you put in the url tag when you get the error) has no value. You loop through all posts so obviously at least one post has an empty slug

Comment: how would I go about checking to see wether it has value?  would it have to be blog.slug instead? I added all my views to my question, Can you spot what I could be doing wrong? @Razenstein . I really appreciate you giving your time to help me

Comment: see detailed answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message

```
Reverse for 'viewblog' with arguments '('',)' not found.
```

> Remark: what is '('',)' ??
>
> it is simply the print of a python list () with one empty argument ('',). The comma just indicates it is a list. This is placed in '' to structure the error message text '('',)'
>
> so this is the list of arguments that is extracted from your {% url .... %} statement for the error message

always means you have and url tag pointing to "viewblog" that requires an argument (because definded like that in urlpatterns in urls.py ) but actually one of them is null or "" (which is not accepted to reverse a valid url):

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('view-blog/<slug:slug>/', views.viewBlog, name='viewblog'),
    ...
]

---------------------------------

href="{% url 'viewblog' post.id %}"
```

Now in your case you had originally post.id as parameter (I understood you changed that to post.slug). That means one of the post database entries has a post.slug that is null or ""

to debug just print the value of post.slug into the html page and you will see what is wrong. the "xxx" and "yyy" are there to mark on the output clearly where some content shoult appear (because without it is more difficult to see if there is an empty output).

```
{% for post in posts %} 

xxx {{ post.slug }} xxx <br>
yyy {{ post.blog_title }} xxx <br>

{% endfor %}
```

Another way of checking post.slug is to go to the admin page ouf your app and inspect the database entries directly

And a third one would be to print the query result for posts in the view:

```
def blogsPage(request):
    posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(blog_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-blog_date')
    context = {'posts': posts}

    for post in posts:
       print(post)

    return render(request, 'blogs.html', context)
```

which will show the content of posts in the console

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, but I don't think i am knowledgeable enough for this yet. I cannot solve it so i will try at a later date

Comment: I take it all back, I fixed by adding slug values manually to my database. thank you.